# What adhesive should I use to glue rigid polystyrene insulation to itself and to wood?

Tags: wood, insulation, adhesive

I have a partial sheet of Polystyrene insulation that I plan to cut into a shape to insulate a square hole, without permanently filling the hole. (The structure will be removable for intermittent access.)

What adhesives are good, and what are bad for gluing this material to itself? I was also considering some spare wainscoting board to use as a backer material... if I were to go this route, which adhesives would also be good for that junction? (This is for use in an attic, so the temperature cycles may be significant, and moist, here in the Southeastern US.)

The material in question:
[image: polystyrene from Lowes]

Specially, would wood glue work? How about latex caulk?

Comment: I would use the latex caulk.

Answer (score 1):

"Project adhesive" or "panel adhesive"  is a variation of construction adhesive that's water-based. It doesn't have solvents that eat foam, and it has reasonably good grab.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend no glue at all.  Just cut it to  fit snug.

Comment: I need to assemble a structure, so this will be part of the solution, but does not answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are construction adhesives specifically made for gluing foam.

Example, not endorsement:

[image: PL300]